# Polynomials Indeterminate

Tags: logic, polynomials

I have a question regarding the concept of indeterminate in polynomials scope.
This is the quotation that drew my attention: "X is not, and does not designate, a number." (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)#Polynomials)
Since the day of being taught of polynomials for the first time I thought that if no one mention the type of indeterminate ( integer, real etc. ) , I presumed that it is complex by default, since the complex array comprises all the possible types of numbers. But I guess that according to wikipedia it does NOT designates a number.
What else can it be? In addition, the quotation seems to tend to evolve to a general conclusion, like the indeterminate itself can't even be a number. I don't understand their perspective at all. It would be great if you helped me with this logical matter. Thanks in advance!
P.s.:Try to limit the terminology to 10th grade.

Comment: We can have complex coffiecients or some other functions of some other variables as well and many more but it still is polynomial

Comment: The only thing we assume is that the coefficients and $x$ lie in some commutative ring. The point is that we want to adjoin an element $x$ to the coefficient ring in the *most general* way possible (so that all more specific adjunctions of an element can be viewed as (ring-theoretic) images of this general adjunction).

Comment: @bill dubuque would you mind to give me a specific example of your explanations? I have no idea what a commutative ring is or what do you mean by adjunction.

Comment: P.s.: try to limit the terminology to 10th grade. Thank you!

Comment: @Anonymus You should add that constraint as context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to think of what's going on, that are, unsurprisingly, all interrelated.

One way is to view a polynomial the finite sequence of its coefficients. So something like $1 + x^2$ would correspond to $(1,0,1)$. From here, you have two choices. You can either take $1 + x^2$ to be an informal notation for specifying such tuples, or you can identify $x$ with $(0,1)$ and directly formulate calculation rules for finite sequences corresponding to polynomials.  This is easy to do, and this approach has a lot to recommend it.

Not quite alternatively, you can directly formalize the "informal notation" of $1+x^2$ by saying a polynomial is a formal syntactic expression involving the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ with constant $0$ and $1$ satisfying the usual laws (commutativity, distribution, etc.). So $1 + x^2$ is, more formally, $1 + x\cdot x$. In this case, we get an algebraic structure, and specifically the algebraic structure of a commutative ring. The set of polynomials (with integer coefficients) is then the free [commutative ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring) on one generator. $x$ stands for that generator. If we additionally add the operation of scaling by elements of a field $k$ with the appropriate laws, we get [associative unital algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra). Polynomials with coefficients in $k$ are then free associative algebras generated from a singleton.  This recovers the finite-sequence-oriented perspective if we equip these algebras with a basis. More generally, we can let $k$ be an arbitrary commutative ring and we can recover the free commutative ring as a free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

The main thing to understand is that a polynomial *gives rise* to a function but is *not itself* a function. Multiple distinct polynomials can give rise to the same function. (If you have any experience with programming, this is like how you can have different implementations of the same function. Indeed, in some sense that's *exactly* what is happening.) As a dramatic case, if we work over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which has only the elements $0$ and $1$, then there are only *four* functions $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2$, which we could express as polynomials as $0$, $1$, $x$, and $1+x$, but there are an infinite number of distinct polynomials, e.g. $1+x^2$ is distinct from all of those four polynomials, though it gives rise to the same function as $1+x$.

Comment: At a 10th grade level, the paragraph starting "One way" is probably the most accessible, and it makes a good exercise to work out what the rules look like in this form, e.g. what does multiplication look like. The concerns brought up in the final paragraph mostly don't come up when the coefficients are real or complex numbers hence the conflation between polynomials and functions that hinders understanding later on.

Comment: How can $x^2+1$ give rise to function $x+1$ ? From what I know, the function being given "birth" by polynomial only contains additionally a domain that restrict the array of values for indeterminate turning into a variable and a co-domain for function values, and the coefficients remain the same.

Comment: I see that you gave me a viewpoint of indeterminate. But I also asked if it can have other values rather than complex numbers. I did some searching and found that polynomials are used in the curves designed for roller coaster, and logically those curves can appear only when the indeterminate is given real values.

Comment: If you view a polynomial, $P$, as a finite sequence of its coefficients with length $N$ with the first labelled $P_0$, then $P_1$ and so forth, then you can make a function $f_P(a)=\sum_{n=0}^N P_na^n$. Take a "normal" polynomial with real coefficients. This gives rise to function on reals, but the *same* polynomial also gives rise to a function on complex numbers, or square matrices with real entries or complex entries, or square matrices whose entries are complex polynomials, or many other things. The polynomial leads to some constraints, but there is an unlimited number of possibilities.

Comment: For your first comment, $x+1$ isn't a function. I said $1+x^2$ gives rise to the same function as $1+x$ (gives rise to) on $\mathbb{Z}_2$. $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has two values $0$ and $1$ that behave as normal except $1+1=0$. This is [modular or clock arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) with only 2 values instead of 12 or 60. As finite sequences, the first polynomial is $(1,0,1)$ while the second is $(1,1)$ which is clearly different. Nevertheless, if $f(a)=1+a^2$ and $g(a)=1+a$, then $f(0)=1=g(0)$ and $f(1)=0=g(1)$, so $f$ and $g$ are the same function on $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!